# Forcefully mark a job as failed in jenkins via cli

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I am new to this jenkins cli. I want to mark the jenkins job as failed such that it will show the red ball instead of blue.

The pipeline will get passed and then it is going to be manually checked by a member of some other team.

I am writing a script by taking input of job name, build number and status(either pass or fail)

So , mostly the case will be like pipeline will be passed and then someone will check it again manually,
If that other team's folk wants to make the job as failed then they should be able to pass the argument that it is failed,
Once the script is executed, I want to make the green ball turn to red if the status is marked as failed.

I did not see anything related to this on jenkins-cli. I am new to this, and need your help in this matter.

Attaching screenshot for further clarification.

I want the pipeline to fail even if it is passed via cli or via any curl command.

[image]

Comment: Once a job is complete, Jenkins will not (and must not) allow the final to be changed.  Why not add error states into pipeline?

Answer (score -1):

If you are running a bash script in your pipeline, then you can do something like this

stage('My Stage') {

```
try {
    sh label: 'My script', script: \'\'\'#!/bin/bash
        { #try
            #some code
        } || { #catch
            exit 1;
        }
        \'\'\'
}
catch (error) {
    currentBuild.result = 'ERROR' 
}
```

}